# Show if the IS is NP-Complete

Tags: computational-complexity, np-complete, satisfiability

Let $G = (V, E)$ be an undirected graph. A subset $I \subseteq V$ of the vertices in $G$ is an *independent set* if no two vertices $u, v \in I$ are adjacent in $G$, i.e., for any $u, v \in I$, we have $(u, v) \not \in E$.

Define the Independent Set Problem (IS) to take as input a graph $G$ and an integer $k$ and determine whether $G$ contains an independent set $I$ with $|I| \ge k$. Show that the IS is NP-complete by proving $3SAT \le_p IS$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please update your questions with the context in which you encountered the problem, what you have already tried and where you are getting stuck. It will make it much easier to guide you properly.